# Creating a trigger in ADO.Net DataTable using RowChanged or other events

Tags: .net, events, datatable, ado.net

I'd like to simulate a trigger in **DataTable** to update my **DataSet** when a certain change to data occurs.
I was going to utilize **DataTable** events for this purpose, but then I found this warning from Microsoft [Handling DataTable Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Data corruption can occur if data is modified in a *DataSet* from which the *RowChanged* event is raised. No exception will be raised if such data corruption occurs.

So, I suppose it's a bad idea to use **RowChanged** event for my task. But is it safe to use other events, like **RowChanging**? Or may be there is a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the MSDN is pointing this out because of potential validation rules that may exist such as keys & unique constraints which are usually part of the actual schema definition of a dataset. So you just need to keep this in mind.

The [RowChanging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanging.aspx) event is more general than the [RowChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged.aspx) event. It tells you that that a change is occurring somewhere in the row, but you won't know which column has changed.

The event you choose comes down to how granular you want to be. RowChanged and [ColumnChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged.aspx) **are** the more granular options.

In the case of **RowChanged**:

> A row has been changed. The event passes the row to you, along with a
>   value indicating what type of action (change, insert, and so on) is
>   being performed.

In the case of **ColumnChanged**:

> The value in a column has been changed. The event passes the row and
>   column to you, along with the proposed value.

Another option is possibly the the [DataTable.GetChanges Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thc1eetk.aspx).

> Calling the GetChanges method of a dataset or data table returns a new
>   dataset or data table that contains only records that have been
>   changed. If you want to get only specific records — for example, only
>   new records or only modified records — you can pass a value from the
>   DataRowState enumeration as a parameter to the GetChanges method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If the only corruption to the data that may happen is breaking some constraint, I can handle it. 
Anyway I'll probably move my code to the ColumnChanged event.

Comment: @AlexVB If the answer solved your problem, please mark the question as answered, so that others can benefit from it as well. Thanks